# passing data from ajax function to another after ajax finishes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Tried to pass data to `jvectormap` from a ajax call, I have `when` function so the code runs after the `ajax` finish load

The problem that I have is that the map is empty and I get a error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: postdata is not defined

This is the code that I currently have

```
            $(document).ready(function() {

            function ajax1() {

                return $.ajax({
                    url: "src/data.php?form_action=call-map",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: postdata,
                    dataType: "text", // the type of data that you're expecting back from the server
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $().toastmessage("showErrorToast",
                            "AJAX call failed: "+textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        //return false;
                    }
                });

            }

            $.when(ajax1()).done(function(a1){

                $('#world-map').vectorMap({
                    map: 'world_mill_en',
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    regionStyle: {
                        initial: {
                            fill: '#e4e4e4',
                            "fill-opacity": 0.9,
                            stroke: 'none',
                            "stroke-width": 0,
                            "stroke-opacity": 0
                        }
                    },

                    series: {
                        regions: [{
                            values: a1,
                            scale: ["#005aad", "#001d38"],
                            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                        }]
                    },
                    onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){
                        el.html(el.html()+ '<br>Time Used: '+mapData[code]);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

This is the return data from the ajax call to the php script

```
{"AF" : 10, "AX" : 22, "AL" : 5, "DZ" : 0, "AS" : 41, "AD" : 74, "AO" : 30}
```

console.log(data); shows all the data that I need to pass to the `jvectormap`.

Comment: What does you `postdata` contains?

Comment: I have to remove that line since I am not sending anything to the script

Comment: what does `console.log(a1)` show inside your done function?  If it's returning a string, you'll need to convert it to an object/array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to  fix the problem by converting the data type in the string using this:

```
var a1 = JSON.parse(a1);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `postdata` variable is not initialized (in the piece of code you posted here!) change this:

```
url: "src/data.php?form_action=call-map",
type: "GET",
data: postdata,
dataType: "text", // the type
```

to this:

```
url: "src/data.php",
type: "GET",
data: "form_action=call-map",
dataType: "text", // the type
```

If however the variable "postdata" has a sense for you, show us where you value it.

Comment: I removed the line I missed that part. The problem I see is that I am not passing the return data from ajax to the other function properly

Comment: @user2661296 Test it with a simple alert, at beggining of "when" function add "alert(a1)" and check the value you see. I just tested your "when" and it work, but I can't know what result you expect in the "a1" variable.

Comment: After doing alert of the var inside the function I get the string that I need

{"AF" : 10, "AX" : 22, "AL" : 5, "DZ" : 0, "AS" : 41, "AD" : 74, "AO" : 30}

but my map still empty, the script tell me that there is not map data to fill the map

Comment: The data seems to be correct, now, I don't know JSvector what format want. If you can, put the only JSVector part, and I'll try to help you. But you have other error in your console browser ?